# cache audio file from link using PHP

Tags: php, caching

SUBJECT: there is a link from external server like somesite.com/audio.mp3
question: how to cache that audio to my server and then let user to use it (listen or dl)?
i tried to google about PHP cache, but could't find anything

Comment: Use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to grab the mp3, save it to disk [fpc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and update any reference you have to the external file to your saved file.

Comment: What the person with the exploded user name said. :) Be careful though, you may not be allowed to copy/host the MP3 file

Comment: all right, after getting the file by file_get_contents, how to CACHE it on server with a specified path?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really caching, it's just copying a file from a remote to local server. You can use PHPs [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.

```
copy('http://somesite.com/audio.mp3', '/local/dir/audio.mp3');
```

Comment: great, it works, but i think it would be better if i could cache it for some period of time

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by caching. Usually a cache is used to store a temporary static version of dynamically generated content. That doesn't really apply to this problem. If you want files to be removed automatically you'll probably have to setup a cron job to remove old files.